# Discord.py Adding Reactions For Poll

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I've got this code for my bot, I'm trying to make a !poll command. In theory, I'll type !poll (question), and then the bot will send my questions as an embed, and under that embed, add a thumbsup and thumbsdown reaction so people can vote. However, I just cannot work out how to make it add the reaction, no matter how hard I try and research. Here's the code:

```
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def poll (ctx, *, message):
    embed=discord.Embed(title="New Poll!", description = message, color=0xff0000)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

So what do I now need to add to my code so it can add a  and  reaction to the embed? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Messageable.send` returns a `discord.Message` instance, you then simply `.add_reaction()`

```py
message = await ctx.send(embed=embed)

await message.add_reaction('')
await message.add_reaction('')
```

Reference:

- [`Messageable.send`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?#discord.abc.Messageable.send)
- [`Message.add_reaction`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?#discord.Message.add_reaction)